# C++ how to delete local allocated char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, local

I wrote a function which receives as a parameter a char pointer,then builds a new dynamic allocated char array that contains that parameter char.Then,it returns the new char array.
This is the function:

```
 char* read_string(char *pstr)

    {
        char *str;
        str = new char[strlen(pstr)];//allocate memory for the new char
        str[strlen(pstr)] = '\0';
        for(unsigned i=0;i<strlen(pstr);i++)//build the new char
            str[i]=pstr[i];
        return str;//then return it
    }
```

In main I have:

```
int main()

    {
        char *Pchar = read_string("Test");

        cout<<Pchar;// Outputs "Test"

        delete [] Pchar;//"Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap." error
    }
```

I declare a char pointer in main and then make it point to the char array that is returned from the read_string function.It outputs what I want but if I want to free the memory it gives me runtime error.How can I free up the memory if I don't need to use Pchar anymore?

EDIT:Thank you all for your very informative answers.I have successfully resolved the problem.

Comment: You have not allocated enough memory for the null character, `str[strlen(pstr)]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @ zenith How can I correct that?

Comment: Don't do any of this nonsense. Use std::string.

Comment: I am not allowed to use STL's in my assignments unfortunately :(

Comment: `strlen` gives the length of the string **without** the terminating null. You need a buffer of size `strlen(pstr) + 1` to hold the null as well.

Comment: @xQd I think the term you're looking for is "standard container"

Comment: What? You're not allowed to use STL? That's so wrong on so many levels. I would love to have a word with your teacher... That's not how they should teach C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate more memory to have space for EOS character:

```
str = new char[strlen(pstr)+1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your specific problem is an off-by-one error:

```
str = new char[strlen(pstr) + 1];
//                         ^^^^ need one more for the '\0'
str[strlen(pstr)] = '\0';
```

Generally, since this is C++ and not C, it would be better to return a smart pointer so the caller knows what the ownership semantics of the pointer are:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> read_string(char *pstr)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> str(new char[strlen(pstr) + 1]);
    // rest as before
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the error occurs due to incorrect length of the allocated string.
You have to use the following record to allocate the string

```
    str = new char[strlen(pstr) + 1];//allocate memory for the new char
    str[strlen(pstr)] = '\0';
```

The function can look the following way

```
char* read_string( const char *pstr )
{
    char *str;
    size_t n = strlen( pstr );

    str = new char[n + 1];//allocate memory for the new char

    strcpy( str, pstr );

    return str;
}
```

Comment: `strcpy` will do the null terminator too, so you don't need that extra assignment.

Comment: @Barry It was a result of copy and paste.:)